# I can't seem to get jQuery to work

Tags: jquery, html, css

Okay, I know there's a fair few of these threads out there to say the least, and I've tried a lot of solutions, but I cannot for the life of me seem to get my jQuery to work. I'm pretty sure I've linked it correctly and I can't see any apparent errors in my code (although I am pretty new to this), and it's getting a little frustrating.

What I've done is created a few divs with a class called "button", and I'm trying to make it so that when you hover over them, they turn semi-opaque, and when you leave them they turn back to normal. However, for some reason, it doesn't appear to be working.

Anyway, here's the relevant part of my HTML:

```
<head>
<title>Testing</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
```

And my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.5);
    });
    $(".button").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
    });
});
```

And my CSS, for good measure (just in case):

```
.button {
height:50px;
width:150px;
border-radius:5px;
background-color:#C7C7C7;
border:2px solid black;
display:inline-block;
text-align:center;
font-size:26px;
line-height:50px;
margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

Comment: Works here http://jsfiddle.net/DLXxE/

Comment: Console errors? Tried logging anything?

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/CS6Qp/.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not running some sort of server, and only testing locally, your issue may be with this line:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Try changing it to:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note the addition of **http://**

Why? You can read in this article regarding headless CDN, but if you are not running a web server locally, then you must include the http://

http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/#protocolless

> The main caveat to keep in mind when using the protocol-less reference
>   is that it will fail on pages loaded via file:/// (i.e. HTML pages you
>   load directly from disk to your browser). So, do be sure to include
>   the http: protocol in the URL if you happen to be developing without a
>   web server at all, but don’t worry about omitting it otherwise.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the speedy reply - my post was barely up for 5 minutes. I tried your suggestion and managed to get it working on Internet Explorer, but not Chrome for some reason.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted; it is an issue which I've come across too (and could be the problem here, but can't be sure without more information). It's because otherwise, file:// is chosen as the protocol when running locally

Comment: I've added more context regarding headless CDN w/o webserver for the downvoter, hopefully that will change their mind :)

Comment: I gave it 1 upvote, the //: doesnt always works, it depends on some settings. It could be very well be the problem.

Comment: // should work with modern browsers. It's a protocol relative url. And googleapis supports both http and https.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, guys. Can you perhaps explain why this works on Internet Explorer, but neither Chrome nor Firefox?

Comment: What (if any) errors are you receiving in Firebug and Inspector?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors with Firebug, nor do I have any actual syntax errors in Notepad++

Comment: Actually, scratch that, it now says: "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must to be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol."

Comment: I believe that is unrelated. That should be resolved by placing this in your head: <meta charset="utf-8">

Comment: I'm making a gist that I can share with you. See if you are still having the same problems if you download and run it locally. Uno momento.

Comment: Please download this gist, which is a reproduction of your project. I've confirmed this to work in Chrome and Firefox. Hope this helps, download it and try it out. If you need more troubleshooting, let's move to chat. https://gist.github.com/kunalbhat/6816461

Comment: Heh - "User2844107 has only 1 reputation, not yet enough to chat". I've downloaded your gist though and, as you say, it does work. I'm starting to think it might be something to do with the fact that I have my buttons within other divs, since I can't see any differences between your code and mine.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the jQueryUI stylesheet.  Try this:

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
</head>
```

Note the last one (which technically should be second, but is easier to notice this way...)